# PHP Unset index if no match

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables that have these columns (I'm only showing revelant ones) :

```
tasks table
+----+------+
| id | todo |
+----+------+
| 1  | 0    |
| 2  | 1    |
| 3  | 1    |
| 4  | 0    |
| 5  | 1    |
+----+------+

entries table
+----+---------+---------+------+
| id | task_id | user_id | done |
+----+---------+---------+------+
| 1  | 3       | 1       | 1    |
| 2  | 5       | 2       | 1    |
| 3  | 5       | 1       | 1    |
| 4  | 2       | 1       | 0    |
+----+---------+---------+------+
```

I query these tables and only keep `tasks` where `todo = 1`, So I already have the data in a PHP object.

I then have two lists that the user can view : tasks that are to do, and archived (done), and tasks that are to do. I can generate the first list just fine, I'm looping through each task and entries if they have a matching `task_id` where `user_id == $loggeduser && done == 1`, and unsetting the index of those that don't match. However, I cannot find a logic to do this with my archive list, as I don't have entries to match. How do I loop my tasks and only keep those that are done, for the user? In this case, for the archive list for user 1, I'm excepting to only keep task id 3 and 5, and for user 2, only keep task id 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all this using plain SQL (I suppose you're using some relational database).

This query gives you all the tasks "todo & done". To get the tasks "todo & not done", just change the "`e.done = 1`" to "`e.done = 0`". I'm sure you get the idea.

```
SELECT * FROM tasks t
  INNER JOIN entries e ON t.id = e.task_id
    AND e.user_id = [logged_user_id]
    AND e.done = 1
WHERE
  t.todo = 0
```

Comment: my first approach was using a join, and I couldn't get it working, thank you, I'll try again :) A bit new with join.